# Mouse picking with gluUnProject not working

Tags: objective-c, opengl, 3d

I'm trying to implement mouse picking using gluUnProject but the vector it returns seems of.

```
/* create ray */
NSPoint mousePosition = [event locationInWindow];
CGFloat clickX = (mousePosition.x/750-0.5)*2;
CGFloat clickY = (mousePosition.y/750-0.5)*2;
    
GLint viewport[4];
GLdouble modelview[16];
GLdouble projection[16];
    
GLdouble nearx, neary, nearz;
GLdouble farx, fary, farz;
    
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    
gluUnProject(clickX, clickY, 0.0f, modelview, projection, viewport, &nearx, &neary, &nearz);
gluUnProject(clickX, clickY, 1.0f, modelview, projection, viewport, &farx, &fary, &farz);
    
NSLog(@"%f %f %f", farx-nearx, fary-neary, farz-nearz);
```

output when clicking

```
2020-08-18 03:00:24.092021+0200 3D[2266:115052] -165.663323 -165.669172 -496.999605
```

The camera is at position (0,0,5) looking at (0,0,0). The click is done at the middle of the window (clickX=0, clickY=0). I expect the direction to be (0,0,-1). The ray should not deviate in a left/bottom direction. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is the [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) current when this event is invoked?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you, the code is now executed in an OpenGL Context.